# How can I do block-oriented disk I/O with Java? Or similar for a B+ tree

Tags: java, io, backend, b-tree

I would like to implement an [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) in Java and try to optimize it for disk based I/O. Is there an API for accessing individual disk blocks from Java? or is there an API that can do similar block-oriented access that fits my purpose?

I would like to create something like [Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) in 100% Java. Is there anyone that knows what Java only databases like [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) is using in the back-end for this?

*I know that there are probably other languages than Java that can do this better, but I do this in a learning purpose only.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head I think that [MappedByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) in NIO could be your best bet. It's basically as-direct-as-possible mapping between HDD and Java.